# Ubuntu Server Raspberry Pi on QEMU

Tags: raspberrypi, qemu, emulation

I would like to do some testing of Ubuntu Server 20.04 Raspberry Pi images I have created.

But I currently don't have a spare raspberry pi to test with.

I've found guides on how to [emulate Raspberry Pi with QEMU](https://blog.agchapman.com/using-qemu-to-emulate-a-raspberry-pi/) but they require a qemu kernel and the ones they reference are for Raspbian.

- Can someone advise on how to emulate Raspberry Pi 4 on x86/amd64 and test Ubuntu Server Pi images?
- Is there a qemu kernel for Ubuntu Raspberry Pi somewhere?

Comment: I'm battling with this exact problem. I managed to get a kernel by loop mounting the ubuntu server 20.04 pi image and grabbing `/boot/vmlinuz` from there. My problem is getting the root partition to be recognised... Will post back here if I make more progress.

Comment: Has there been any progress made on this front?

Comment: No, I havn't found an answer sadly. I ended up waiting until I was physically able to access a raspberry pi 4 and do the testing.

Answer (score -1):

Found this link:
https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/20.04.2/release/

- Pre-installed server images for Raspberry Pi on Ubuntu 20.04

However, I could not find the QEMU command and options to use for Raspberry Pi.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RISC-V
The command and options were provided for the RISC-V Unleashed board.

```
qemu-system-riscv64 \
-machine virt -nographic -m 2048 -smp 4 \
-bios /usr/lib/riscv64-linux-gnu/opensbi/generic/fw_jump.elf \
-kernel /usr/lib/u-boot/qemu-riscv64_smode/uboot.elf \
-device virtio-net-device,netdev=eth0 -netdev user,id=eth0 \
-drive file=focal-preinstalled-server-riscv64.img,format=raw,if=virtio
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSdzJ.png)